# Change List of Strings to List of Integer

Tags: haskell

First of all, sorry for my bad english. I'm not native and try my best :)

Now to the problem: i have a list of Strings and want to convert them to a list of integers. The Problem is, it's not just numbers, basically the String is a List to.

```
["[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]","[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]","[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]"]
```

This is the result i get from my code i'll post further down.

Any idea how i can achieve, that the internal list of numbers are list of integers?
I tried like three hours and didn't find a solution.

Every help is appreciatet.

Kind regards

```
get "/authors/:author" $ do
     authorName <- param "author"
     directories <- liftIO(listDirectory("data/" ++ authorName))
     liftIO(readFiles directories authorName)
     html (T.pack (HtmlModule.h1 ("Author: " ++ authorName)))


readFiles :: [String] -> String -> IO ()
readFiles x authorName = do
  let y =  addPrefix x authorName
  content <- mapM readFile y
  putStrLn (show content)

Result: ["[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]","[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]","[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`read`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/read_f.html) the string into a list of ints:

```hs
let nums = map read content :: [[Int]]
```

Comment: If i could i would marry you! Thank you so much. I tried this approach simillarly but it didn't work. Your solution works like a charm. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`read :: Read a => String -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) to convert a string to a type that is a member of the [**`Read`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Read).

Since `Int` is a member of the `Read` typeclass, and `[a]` is a member of the `Read` typeclass if `a` is a member of the `Read` typeclass, we thus can read a list of `Int`s:

```
Prelude> read "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]" :: [Int]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

We thus can convert a list of `String`s with:

```
    content <- mapM ((read :: String -> [Int]) . readFile) y
```

`read` will raise an error in case the `String` can not be converted. You can make use of [**`readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) to wrap the result in a `Just` in case parsing was successful, and `Nothing` in case parsing failed.

Comment: Same to you. Thank you so much for your help. It is much appreciated!

Comment: To get a "Maybe" value if a read fails, use [`traverse`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:traverse): `traverse (readMaybe @[Int])` which has the type `Traversable t => t String -> Maybe (t [Int])`. `@[Int]` is an example of [visible `-XTypeApplications`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html?highlight=xtypeapplications#extension-TypeApplications). I prefer writing, say `read @[Int] <$> content`, to `read <$> content :: [[Int]]`